# What is this piece, that fell out of my Kenmore Dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Model #66513593K600 Kenmore dishwasher.  I had a fuse problem, and replaced it, but after I put it back together, I found that this part had fallen out and I'm not sure what it is or where it came from!  What is it?

I think this is the right Sears page, but I can't find the piece on there: https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/66513593k600/0582/0130000.html

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, never mind, I found it!  Dishwasher tub corner baffle.

[image]